# Adding CRLF to a string in a string array creates a space character in ballerina.io

Tags: ballerina

I am trying to add CRLF in a string array.

```
function example() returns string [] {
    string[] a= ["Test\n", "Test\n" ,"Test"];
    log:printInfo(a.toString());
    log:printInfo(stringutils:replaceAll(a.toString()," ",""));
    return a;
}
```

Output:

```
log:printInfo(a.toString()); :

Test
 Test
 Test
```

Output:

```
log:printInfo(stringutils:replaceAll(a.toString()," ",""));

Test
Test
Test
```

Why is a space added after \n?

Are there other ways to add a CRLF?

versions: ballerina --version
jBallerina 1.2.8
Language specification 2020R1
Update Tool 0.8.8

Many greetings, Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. When you call `toString()` on an array it adds a space between the elements of the array.

For an example;

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    string[] fruitsArray = ["Apple", "Orange", "Strawberry"];
    string fruits = fruitsArray.toString();
    io:println(fruits);
}
```

This prints the following:

```
Apple Orange Strawberry
```

In your case, this seems weird since you have a CRLF at the end of the string. But if you take one element from the array, it does not contain the space.